Deducing if a language is in $R \setminus P, P$ or $\notin R$
Let $A \in P$, and some language $B$. We have $f:\{0,1\}^{*}\to\{0,1\}^{*}$ s.t $\forall x \in \{0,1\}^{*}$ we have: $x \in B \iff f(x) \in A$.
In addition we know that there exists a family of cycles of polynomial size $C=\{C_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ that computes $f$. Which is True:

$B \in P$
$B \in R$ but not necessarily $\in P$
$B$ not necessarily $\in R$


So I was thinking that given the fact that $C$ is polynomial and computes $f$ that we can deduce $B \leq_p A$ and therefore $A \in P \implies B \in P$.
The correct answer is $3$ unfortunately.
I'd love some help.
Thanks in advance!

Compuability by a polynomial circuit family is quite different from polynomial time (Turing) computability, so you can't just say there is a reduction by the latter type just because there is one of the former type.
The thing to remember is that some non-computable languages can be decided by polynomial circuit families. The standard example is $\{1^n: n\in X\}$ for an arbitrary non-computable set $X$. It's easy to see that for any $n$, there is an $O(n)$-sized circuit on $n$ inputs that decides if the input is all ones, so let $C_n$ be that if $n\in X,$ and otherwise a circuit that always outputs $0.$
Then, just let $f$ be the function computed by this $O(n)$ circuit family and $A=\{1\},$ and we'll have $B=\{1^n: n\in X\}$, which is not computable, since $X$ is computable from it.

Thank you very much! I appreciate it!
